# How to get category a product belongs to - Laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am fetching products and in the response, i want the category it belongs to to appear in the response. When i log the response, it looks like the below

**Response**

```
 [{"items_receive":"280","category":null},`{"items_receive":"100","category":null}]`
```

**Product.php**

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
}

 public function getSummary()
    {
        return Product::with('category')->selectRaw('SUM(items_receive) as 
         items_total)
                ->where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)
                ->groupBy('category_id')
                ->get();
    }
```

**Category.php**

```
 public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
    }
```

**Controller.php**

```
 public function index(Product $product)
 {
       $product->getSummary(); 
 }
```

Comment: you may want to try to select the foreign key to see if it is having trouble matching the parent without having that key ... though we can only assume the relationship is setup correctly and exists in the database

Answer (score 0):

Since relationships are lazy loaded for performance reasons, you have to explicitely ask for them, aka eager loading:

```
Product::with('category')->all();
```

[Related Laravel documentation page](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

Comment: `return Product::with('category')...`  looks like they are attempting to eager load  (which is why the output has `category` in it)